# How to apply sorting in array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am having lots of confusion while applying sorting to my array of objects. I want this array to be sorted for implementing a multi-line chart in d3.js.

I want to display the top 3 `type` values in my chart based on the `count` in descending order. The problem is that the top 3 `type` may be different for `build` values, eg. `Build 1` and `Build 2`. Therefore I need the top 3 for `Build 2` only and then the same for `Build 1`, whether they have the highest count or not. It will help me to take top `type` in the latest build.

My requirement is a little weird, but I need to implement the logic this way.

```js
[{
  "type": "Assignment",
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "10"
}, {
  "type": "Assignment",
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "20"
}, {
  "type": "Initialization",
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "10"
}, {
  "type": "Initialization",
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "70"
}, {
  "type": "Coding",
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "30"
}, {
  "type": "Coding",
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "40"
}, {
  "type": "Data",
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "80"
}, {
  "type": "Data",
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "10"
}, {
  "type": "Condition",
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "10"
}, {
  "type": "Condition",
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-15",
  "count": "10"
}]
```

Can anyone please help me to apply sorting to this array so that I can display the top 3 entries instead of a complete array in my chart.

The output I want is this:

```js
  [{
    "type": "Assignment",
    "build": "Build 1",
    "date": "2019-08-15",
    "count": "10"
  }, {
    "type": "Assignment",
    "build": "Build 2",
    "date": "2019-08-15",
    "count": "20"
  }, {
    "type": "Initialization",
    "build": "Build 1",
    "date": "2019-08-15",
    "count": "10"
  }, {
    "type": "Initialization",
    "build": "Build 2",
    "date": "2019-08-15",
    "count": "70"
  }, {
    "type": "Coding",
    "build": "Build 1",
    "date": "2019-08-15",
    "count": "30"
  }, {
    "type": "Coding",
    "build": "Build 2",
    "date": "2019-08-15",
    "count": "40"
  }]
```

This is because this array contains top issues for build 2, having count as 20,70, and 40.

Comment: Can  you show exactly the output you want for that given input?

Comment: _“So that I can display top 3 entries instead of a complete JSON in my chart”_ — so do you want to sort the entire object or display only the top three entries?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: @Jamiec I have attached final json in question.

Comment: Note that nothing about this is JSON, so I've removed all references to it in the question. What you have is an array of objects. Also note that you need plain JS to do this, not jQuery as that is primarily a tool for DOM manipulation.

Comment: I don't see the logic in how the final output is achieved. Half the original objects are missing, and the values don't seem to correlate at all. There is nothing 'top 3' about any of it.

Comment: Top 3 are based on count..I have taken top 3 issues for Build 2. And this will be needed in multi line chart, so it is obvious same 3 type which i have taken for Build 2 should be there for Build 1 as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
const processJson = (json, build) => {
  const extract = json.filter(e => e.build === build);
  const others = json.filter(e => e.build !== build);
  
  const sorted = extract.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
  
  return others.concat(sorted).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // check if there is already 3 values of the build we are processing
    if (acc.filter(v => v.build === cur.build).length < 3) {
       acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const json = [{"type":"Assignment","build":"Build 1","date":"2019-08-15","count":"10"},{"type":"Assignment","build":"Build 2","date":"2019-08-15","count":"20"},{"type":"Initialization","build":"Build 1","date":"2019-08-15","count":"10"},{"type":"Initialization","build":"Build 2","date":"2019-08-15","count":"70"},{"type":"Coding","build":"Build 1","date":"2019-08-15","count":"30"},{"type":"Coding","build":"Build 2","date":"2019-08-15","count":"40"},{"type":"Data","build":"Build 1","date":"2019-08-15","count":"80"},{"type":"Data","build":"Build 2","date":"2019-08-15","count":"10"},{"type":"Condition","build":"Build 1","date":"2019-08-15","count":"10"},{"type":"Condition","build":"Build 2","date":"2019-08-15","count":"10"}];

console.log(processJson(json, 'Build 2'));
```

Comment: There is a little issue with the final output. For Build 2 sorted is applied correctly, but for Build 1 also, it is sorting the data. Ideally what i want is same type for both the build

Comment: I mean to say sorting should be done only for latest build, i.e., Build 2. For Build 1, I just need to fetch the same records based on "type".

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary Changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** I've got my head around what you're trying to do...

```
function sortData(input, chosenBuild) {
  var groups = {};
  var topThreeTypes = [];
  var output = [];

  input.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length && topThreeTypes.length < 3; i++) {
    var item = input[i];
    if (item.build == chosenBuild) topThreeTypes.push(item.type);
  }

  topThreeTypes.forEach(type => {
    var items = input.filter(item => item.type == type);
    items.forEach(item => {
      var key = JSON.stringify({ build: item.build, type: item.type });
      if (typeof groups[key] === 'undefined') groups[key] = item;
    });
  });

  Object.keys(groups).forEach(key => output.push(groups[key]));

  output.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.type + a.build < b.type + b.build) return -1;
    if (a.type + a.build > b.type + b.build) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  return output;
}
```

Then call `sortData(yourInputArray, chosenBuild)` to fetch the results (e.g. `var results = sortData(input, "Build 2")`)